# Query to not show IF value is <= "0"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=QUERY({A2:C,index(D2:D*if(C2:C="close",-1,1))},"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col4) 
where Col2 is not null group by Col1, Col2 label Col1 'Trade ID', Col2 'Asset', sum(Col4) 'Amount'")
```

Looking to adjust this formula to hide the end result if the value in 'amount' is <= 0

[image]

what it currently looks like

[image]

what it should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like your previous question:

```
=QUERY(QUERY........,"WHERE Col3 >0")
```

Comment: The formulas I was trying were calculating it before hand. Where I want it to filter post query. Maybe I'm looking for another function.

Comment: It's a Filter post QUERY, you have to wrap your query on another QUERY, as in your prior question